# Count the occurence of a alphabet before a particular letter

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to count the occurence of "I" before first "C" occurs at each Id level. I have tried this code but can able to count all "I" present in the column.
Code I tried

```
library(plyr)
Impres = ddply(df, .(Id), summarize, No_of_I_before_First_C = length(which(Character == "I")))
```

Sample data

```
Id  Character
1     I
1     I
1     C
1     I
2     I
2     C
```

Output should be like this

```
Id  Count_Of_I_before_First_C
1     2
2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea,

```
first1 <- function(x, letter){
           which(x == letter)[1]-1
           }

aggregate(Character ~ Id, df, first1, 'C')
#  Id Character
#1  1         2
#2  2         1
```

To generalize it a bit more,

```
first1 <- function(x, letter, letter_count){
    ind <- which(x == letter)[1]
    sum(grepl(letter_count, x[1:ind]))
    }

aggregate(Character ~ Id, df, first1, 'C', 'I')
#  Id Character
#1  1         2
#2  2         1
```

Comment: This will be slow on reasonably large dataset

Comment: @Bulat I was only following the `agregate` tag of the question (i.e. no packages). I know that both `dplyr` and `data.table` have much more efficient ways

Answer (score 0):

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(Id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2), Character = c('I', 'I', 'C', 'I', 'I', 'C'))
```

This function will give you number of I's before the first C

```
foo <- function (character) {

  is_before_C <- (character == 'C') %>% cummax() %>% not()
  # is_before_C <- !cummax(character == 'C') # the same
  is_I <- character == 'I'
  is_I_before_C <- is_I & is_before_C

  return(sum(is_I_before_C))
}
```

And then you can use this function to summarise the data

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(Count_Of_I_before_First_C = foo(Character))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     Id Count_Of_I_before_First_C
  <dbl>                     <int>
1     1                         2
2     2                         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2), Character = c('I', 'I', 'C', 'I', 'I', 'C'))
dt[, cnt.c := cumsum(Character == "C"), by = Id]
res <- dt[cnt.c == 0, .(Count_Of_I_before_First_C = length(Character)), by = Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
library(dplyr)

rlei <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  I <- which(r$values=="I")
  C <- which(r$values=="C")
  r$lengths[which(I<C)][1]
}

group_by(df, Id) %>% 
  summarise(Count_Of_I_before_First_C=rlei(.$Character))
```